# ACRA not sending queued crash report

Tags: android, acra

I am using ACRA for error reporting , when internet is not available and their is some error it gets queued to send but does not get trigged unless their is new error. 
Is their any way to trigger forcefully as soon as internet is available ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is

1) No, because to listen to network state requires a BroadcastListener and a permission that most are unlikely to want to grant. If you'd like to provide a pull request then I'm happy to review it. But it should only enable **IF** the permission has been granted.

2) No, but it will be sent when your app is restarted and you do have internet coverage.

Think about crash reporting from a statistical point of view and you will realise that it *generally* doesn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't fall under _generally_: I'm using ACRA for a stand-alone Service, and the lifecycle of that service is not under my control (it might be just always running). Would there be an easy way to integrate a trigger e.g. via a static method or an Intent which I could call periodically or when my service detects connectivity changes? Could I e.g. use the `SenderServiceStarter` manually?

Comment: @William any update on this? Is there maybe already a method available for triggering the sending of reports?

Comment: Sorry @KapiteinWitbaard I don't maintain #ACRA anymore, so I haven't been following developments in this space.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***Sending reports for caught exceptions or for unexpected application state without any exception*** when internet available(check using receiver and use below way)

You could also want your application to send a report without any Exception thrown, just because you know that your application is in an unexpected state.

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(caughtException);
```

If you need to add silent trace reports whatever notification mode you configured for your application, you can also use:

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(caughtException);
```

check [documentation](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage) for more details

Comment: Problem with the above approach is whenever internet is available i have to report either a null or dummy exception which will increase count of exception on Hockeyapp without any actual reason.